# Is there a way to change my ODE inside ODEINT in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic, ode, odeint

I'm trying to simulate an oscillatory system with a little difference: I want it to use a specific equation of motion (an O.D.E.) when the body is moving up, and another equation of motion when the body is moving down. To solve these equations, I'm using the ODEINT from Scypi.

For example, let's consider the classic mass-spring system. I've tried to induce the system to work with the equation of motion for external excitations on the body when it's moving up, and with the simple equation when it's moving down.

```
def function (x,t):

    F0 = 10.00
    w = 1.00
    m = 2.00
    c = 1.00
    k = 20.00
    s = x[0]
    dsdt = x[1]

    if x[1] >= 0:
        d2sdt2 = (F0*np.sin(w*t)-c*dsdt-k*s)/m
    else:
        d2sdt2 = (-c*dsdt-k*s)/m

    result = [dsdt,d2sdt2]
    return result

initial = [3.00,0.00]
t = np.linspace(0.00,10.00,101)
y = odeint(function, initial, t)
```

The results obtained show that only the second equation of motion is working on the body ([Results Obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYBZA.png)). I was expecting a more chaotic pattern of movement when the body is moving up, due the external force.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: How do you detect that only the second branch is working? Are you using some debug output?

Comment: Try with increasing your sampling density. Also, dashed lines are not very well suited to visually detect slight kinks. These should be well visible in the derivative curve in the second half of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding some parameters to increase the density of internal steps and the density of the output

```
t = np.linspace(0.00,10.00,301)
y = odeint(function, initial, t, hmax=0.1, atol = 1e-8, rtol=1e-10)
```

and not using dashed lines gives the plot
[image]

where the kinks in the second half are clearly visible.

So your code is correct, but you need to take into account that the ODE solvers are constructed for smooth right sides, starting with the mathematical methods and up to and especially for the predictors for the optimal step size. As here there are locally unpredictable non-smooth changes in the right side, one has to tell the solver not to use very large step sizes as that may jump over a change of the model phase and back.

As an aside, for smooth plots an output density of 100 points on the whole horizontal axis is usually too small. Use 200 to 600 points depending on the final "in-print" size of the plot.

Comment: I wasn't using any debug to check if the equations were being used correctly. I was just checking it visually, expecting more drastic changes.
Your suggestions worked fine, but when I change some parameters on this example or when I try to use it with the code I'm working with, I get the "excess work done on this call". Could the method be not suitable to evaluate this changes on the ODEs?

Comment: What I observed is that for higher driving frequencies the system diverges to infinity. Also, the switching mechanism acts like a driving term that is in resonance with the oscillation frequency of the linear operator. This is more likely than not the reason for the "excess work", with the values the derivatives become so large that the tolerances can only be kept for increasingly small step sizes.